# Decode MULTIPLE objects JSON objects from a file to a python dictionary with (raw_decode)

Tags: python, json, object, decode

New in python :)

I want to decode a long json file containing multiple objects to a python dictionary then process it to a database.

Here,is my code

```
file=open('hi.json',encoding='utf-8')
def readin():
    return file.read(2048)
def parse():
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder(strict=False)
    buffer = ''
    for chunk in iter(readin, ''):
        buffer += chunk
        while buffer:
            try:
                result, index = decoder.raw_decode(buffer)
                yield result
                buffer = buffer[index:]
            except ValueError as e:
                print("1",e)
                 # Not enough data to decode, read more
                break
def main():
    imputd=parse()
    output = open('output.txt', 'w')
    output.write(json.dumps(next(imputd)))
main()
```

It works but just for the first object .Instead of a file (output.txt) ,I want a python dictionary .

Any suggestion please :)

Comment: `imputd` is a generator object. To get the remaining objects, call `next(imputd)` until it raises `StopIteration`.

Comment: @Barmar That's a problem with the producer, not the consumer. Using `raw_decode` is the way to work around that problem.

Comment: What should I do pls?  @chepner

Answer (score 0):

You are only fetching the first value returned from `imputd`, as Rawing said. You need to iterate over the entire sequence it can return.

```
def main():
    imputd = parse()
    objs = list(imputd)   # Get them all, not just the first
    with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
        # Encode the entire list and write it to the output file.
        json.dump(objs)
```

In `parse`, you need to ensure that `buffer` begins with a valid JSON object after you skip past the one just parsed. This should mean just trimming any leading whitespace from `buffer` (assuming the stream contains one object per line, so that `buffer[index:] == "\n..."`).

```
try:
    result, index = decoder.raw_decode(buffer)
    yield result
    buffer = buffer[index:].lstrip()
```

Comment: See update; your buffer wasn't quite ready for the next call to `raw_decode`.

Comment: IT  WORKS! I simply transform my json file adding [ ] to include whole objects.Then I decode it with json.loads and got an array with dictionaries.It is even easier to parse :)  Thank you .